# Does chrome.storage.managed policy work for self-hosted extensions?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-apps

I am trying to configure an extension using the method described at [Manifest for storage areas](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest/storage)
. I'm pretty sure I have everything set up correctly, but I am not seeing the policy value in `chrome://policy`(it is shown as `Not set`) and, obviously, there is no policy seen from

`chrome.storage.managed.get(null,(d)=>{console.log(d)});`

I've checked my schema and the config file I uploaded in the Admin Panel at https://www.jsonschemavalidator.net and it seems to match. It's very simple, `schema.json` is

```
{
    "type" : "object",

    "properties" : {
        "PolicyTest" : {
            "type" : "string"
        }
    }
}
```

and in the json file

```
{
    "PolicyTest" : "test"
}
```

Before I spend a bunch of time debugging this, I thought I would quickly ask- could this be because the extension that I am configuring this for is not hosted on the Chrome Web Store? It's hosted myself using the method described at [Autoupdating](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/autoupdate).

Other than that, I'm not really sure why this isn't working- the device running Chrome is Linux, although I have also checked on a managed Chromebook, and I've checked things like making sure I've selected the right OU, refreshing the policy, and so on.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok, I figured it out by reference to the [Chromium documentation](https://www.chromium.org/administrators/configuring-policy-for-extensions). To answer the question in my title- yes, it works fine for extensions not hosted on the Web Store, I just had the wrong format for my options.

Basically, my json file didn't actually match the schema. For the schema I posted in my question, you actually need this :

```
{
    "PolicyTest" : {
        "Value" : "test"
    }
}
```

Basically, your properties need to be an object with a `Value` field. The core sentence that I missed is : `The txt file should contain a valid JSON object, mapping a policy name to an object describing the policy.`

Mea cupla, I should have read the documentation more carefully. It's quite frustrating that the official Chrome extension developer documentation doesn't have a simple example of a schema and a matching config file, since there is no UI feedback if your format is wrong.

I note also there was some [plan](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=389061) to publish a tool to build a template from a schema. I guess that never happened, it would be useful too.